# Angular 6 : calculating the sum of a list (Observable)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of Orders and want to create an observable that gives the calculated sum of prices. I'm using Angular 6.

```
import { map, reduce, isEmpty } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

  list$: Observable<IOrder[]>;
  total$: Observable<number>;
  empty$: Observable<boolean>;


ngOnInit() {
    this.list$ = this.service.asList.asObservable(); // asList is a BehaviorSubject
    this.empty$ = this.list$.pipe(isEmpty());
    this.total$ = this.list$.pipe(
      map(order => order.price),  // <-- Property 'price' does not exist on type 'IOrder[]'
      reduce((total, price) => total + price, 0)
    );
}
```

'order' inside the map operator is a Order[] instead of a Order.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'IOrder[]
```

That means that your Observable does not return stream of elements one by one (and that's what you expect here), but whole array at once - single result is emitted. Instead of `map` to property, perform `reduce` on array right away.

It will be something like this

```
   this.total$ = this.list$.pipe(
      map(order => order.reduce((total, price) => total + price, 0),'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.total$ = this.list$.pipe(
  mergeMap((list: number[]) => from(list).pipe(
    reduce((totalPrice: number, currentPrice: number) => totalPrice + currentPrice)
  ))
);
```

This is another solution you can use