# sum in list of observale in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**This is my code**

**//Service method**

```
 private cartObs$: BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

   getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
        return this.cartObs$.asObservable();
      }
```

**//method in component**

```
sum$: Observable<number>;

this.sum$ = this.cartService
          .getCartItems()
          .pipe(map((cart) =>
           cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty, 0)));
```

i need to calculate sum of qty in rxjs. am getting error if obeservable is empty
how to calculate sum in rxjs with empty list

I am following similar to this [arrayof obervable sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126017/angular-6-calculating-the-sum-of-a-list-observable)

Thanks in advance

ERROR

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (https://cddm0ddd.ddd.app/src/app/components/header/header.component.ts:17:50)

    at MapSubscriber._next (https://cugm0.csb.app/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js:47:29)

    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (https://cugm0.csb.app/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:73:12)

    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (https://cugm0.csb.app/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js:34:18)

    at BehaviorSubje
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your `this.cartObs$` is of type BehaviorSubject and by default it require to set default value. So I think you are setting default value to null instead of an empty array or you are emmiting null to your subject.

So I see two options here:

Set to empty array `private cartObs$: BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);`

Second fix reducer so it can handle null values ( I think this is safest way since then you dont care if someone will push null into your subject)

```
this.sum$ = this.cartService
          .getCartItems()
          .pipe(map((cart) => cart ? 
           cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty, 0)) : 0);
```

`cart ? cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty, 0)) : 0` this means if cart is not null run reduce of its null return 0

Comment: Thanks ..i have wriiten private cartObs$: BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);  What change i have to do?

Comment: new BehaviorSubject([])

Comment: Ive updated my answer I would basically recommend you to fix it from reducer side too @Glen

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution @VovaBilyachat solves the issue, there are some edge cases where it might exhibit erroneous behavior.

Consider the following

**1. Default value empty array**

In this case the `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with an empty array as default value.

```js
private cartObs$: BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

In this case you'd get the same error as the question if some component would push `null` or `undefined` to it like `cartObs$.next(null)`.

**2. Checking if the value is defined inside `map`**

While this would the issue from solution 1, it still returns the sum as `0` while the input array is either `null` or `undefined`. This might not be expected from the usage PoV of the `sum$` observable.

To tackle these you could use the [`filter`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) operator in the `sum$` observable to use the `cartObs$` emissions only when they are defined.

```js
this.sum$ = this.cartService.getCartItems().pipe(
  filter(cart => (!!cart && !!(cart.length))),
  map((cart: any) => cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.qty, 0))
);
```

---

That said, if the `BehaviorSubject`'s default value isn't used anywhere, I'd recommend you to use [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 instead. It'll also "hold" the current value and emit it to future subscribers without the need for a default value.

```js
private cartObs$: ReplaySubject<CartItem[]> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

Comment: 1. is not right have a look at map it has check for null. Secondly why I think filter is wrong solution because it will stop propagating value. So lets say if you do cartObs$.next([]) or even cartObs$.next(null) my expectation would be to get 0 on my subscription. Lastly there is no point to use replaySubject. ReplaySubject(1) = BehaviorSubject because as soon as you subscribe to BehaviorSubject it will give you last value

Comment: @VovaBilyachat: I agree the case 2 is subjective. Some workflow require notification propagation and some might not. I do not however agree `ReplaySubject(1)` = `BehaviorSubject`. If we're sure there would be no `null` or `undefined` inputs to the observable and the default isn't required, using `ReplaySubject(1)` would completely remove the need for checking against `null` or `undefined`. The whole question could be averted. But it depends on the use case.

Comment: about null my point is different check my map it has safety against null.